# Float overflow in C#

Tags: c#, windows

What happens if I try to stuff a number bigger than `float.MaxValue` in a float?

I have this in my code:

```
int a;
float x;
float y;

...

float b = (a * x) / y;
```

I have two questions about this:

1. Is the result of (a * x) stored in a temp bigger than a float? And is this only done when the result passes `float.MaxValue`?
2. Do I get an exception when the result of the sum is stuffed into `a`? And if not, how should I handle this to prevent disaster?

Comment: Did you try and see what happens?

Comment: Why don't you just run it and find out?

Comment: Just try it, your computer will not explode ;)

Comment: `a*x` is indeed stored in a temporary "variable"

Comment: You'll get `float.PositiveInfinity` (or `float.NegativeInfinity`)... Or you'll just remain in `float.MaxValue` (`float.MaxValue + 1 == float.MaxValue`)

Comment: Overflow does not give exceptions.

Comment: He probably wants to ask about the RHS; means how the runtime will evaluate the RHS and in what type it will store the expression result before assigning it to the float variable.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom I tried it and my laptop exploded. I'm commenting on my phone and typing with my nose.

Comment: @FastAl ups....

Comment: my computer physically prevents me entering anything like this at the keyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get `float.PositiveInfinity` (or `float.NegativeInfinity`)... Or you'll just remain in `float.MaxValue` (`float.MaxValue + 1 == float.MaxValue`)... floating points have a "resolution", that becomes lower the greater the floating point is... The distance between the last two floating points is about...

> 3,40282347E+38: float.MaxValue
>
> 3,40282326E+38: previous float
>
> 2,028241E+31: difference <--------- 2*2^31!

calculated through

```
float nearMaxValue = BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(float.MaxValue), 0) - 1), 0);
Console.WriteLine("{0:R}: float.MaxValue", float.MaxValue);
Console.WriteLine("{0:R}: previous float", nearMaxValue);
Console.WriteLine("{0:R}: difference", float.MaxValue - nearMaxValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to put inside a float a number bigger than float.MaxValue, it will be "Infinity"

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, the calculation is indeed done in the computer's memory. This is always the case.
2. No, an overflow does not cause an exception.

As for what will happen if you run this code snippet (after cleaning up the errors):

```
float b = (a * x) / y;
Console.WriteLine(b);

Output: +infinity

a = (int)b;
Console.WriteLine(a);

Output: -2147483648
```